# ionic 2 start fails with error with the spawned command

Tags: windows, ionic-framework, ionic2

have installed ionic 2 beta on windows 7

```
npm install -g ionic@beta
```

seems to install ok. it's 2.0.0-beta.25

when I try to create a project

```
ionic start test tabs --v2 --ts
```

it fails on the Installing npm packages ... bit with

```
Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
```

would appreciate any help...

Comment: what your npm version ? upgrading npm to > 2.0.0 works for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I too faced the similar problem. Revert to 2.0.0-beta.22 by running the following command:

npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.22

Many people reporting this issue with 2.0.0-beta.25

Comment: Same issue here using ionic 2.0.0-beta.30

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was in npm... After updating `npm install -g npm` it to v3.10 everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Updating NPM a Node.js worked for me on Windows:

- Win 7, Prof
- NPM version: 3.10.2
- Node.js version: 4.4.6

Command ***ionic start test sidemenu --2 --ts*** worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me

`ionic start test tabs --v2 --skip-npm`

`cd test`

`npm install`

it seems to be a bug of ionic or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Recreating new app on same directory and with same name by overwriting the older works for me!