# ionic 1.3 does not start new app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I installed ionic v 1.3 which was successfully installed(means there were no errors during installation). After installing, when I ran following command

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

then it gives below outputs

```
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Installing npm packages...
Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
Caught exception:
 undefined
```

Then I also ran below command in project directory

```
ionic serve
```

which gives me below output

```
Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an Ionic project?
```

I also uninstall and reinstall ionic but still getting above errors.

**How can I solve these problems?**

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [ionic 2 start fails with error with the spawned command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752157/ionic-2-start-fails-with-error-with-the-spawned-command) I'm guessing you may need to update your version of node and npm.